# Add additional kafka consumer settings with sparklyr

Tags: sparklyr

I am trying to connect to a secured Kafka server with sparklyr. However to access it you need to specify the correct security settings (protocol, password etc). But when specified within the read_options, they aren't passed to the consumer config. Here the R-Code:

```
library(sparklyr)
config <- spark_config()
config$sparklyr.shell.packages <- "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local",config=config, version="2.4.0")

read_options <- list(
  kafka.bootstrap.servers='test.server',
  group.id="name",
  security.protocol='SSL',
  ssl.key.password="password",
  ssl.keystore.location="C:/Users/...",
  ssl.keystore.password="password",
  ssl.truststore.location="C:/Users/...",
  ssl.truststore.password="password",
  subscribe = "topic")

stream <- stream_read_kafka(sc, options = read_options)
```

If we have a look at the log of spark, only the server is listed in the consumer config: (shortened version)

```
INFO ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values: 
    bootstrap.servers = [test.server]
    ....
    group.id = spark-kafka-source-7bb43fe7-56b2-4e19-9162-371e4db2075a-1047255113-driver-2
    ....
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    ...
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ..
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
```

Is there a possibility/workaround to add the necessary settings to the consumer?

**Update**

See answer of user1278798

For someone with the same problem it is important to add, that not all settings are supported by spark ( e.g. group.id or auto.offset.reset). Just check out the link given by user1278798.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clearly explained in [the official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

> Kafka’s own configurations can be set via `DataStreamReader.option` **with `kafka.` prefix**, e.g, `stream.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host:port")`.

You options are missing the prefix.